# Is there any solution to convert Android app to Nokia symbian or java?

Tags: java, android, symbian, nokia

I have to run my Android app on another platform, such as Nokia Symbian or Java. Is there any solution for such a conversion?

Comment: I Think no. this would be not so easy.

Comment: @Tarsem Your edit is not appropirate, as code formatting is not needed in this case.

Comment: @Tarsem Generally, you should keep edits clear and simple. Italics is fine as long as it's used *sparingly*.

Comment: I think you need to write yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The APIs are far too intertwined with the Android OS. Symbian or Java will not offer the same set of classes for display, OS integration, apps, accelerometor/sensors, and almost anything else.

You can, however, refactor OS-agnostic code into new classes and reuse those for Java platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You better try sencha phone gap to create application run on different platforms..

Comment: The phone gap using HTML and CSS, and it has a lot of bug and LAG!